# Мешают define макросы min и max

Tags: c++, visual-studio, макросы

Я программирую в среде Visual Studio 2017 на C++14.
Проблема в том, что когда я пишу `std::min` и `std::max`, я получаю сообщение от компилятора "Требуется идентификатор". Это возникает из-за define, который подставляет вместо имён функций другой код.
Я использую библиотеки glad и glfw3 для работы с OpenGL, а сам define лежит в minwindef.h

```
#ifndef max
#define max(a,b) (((a) > (b)) ? (a) : (b))
#endif
```

Мне не хочется, чтобы этот define применялся к моему коду. Что я могу сделать?

[image: описание ошибки]

Comment: Попробуйте начать программу с `#define NOMINMAX`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Есть несколько способов решения проблемы макросов `min`, `max` в заголовочных файлах Windows.

1. Использовать `#define NOMINMAX` в коде перед явным или косвенным включением заголовочного файла с определением макросов `min`, `max`.
2. Иногда бывает не сразу очевидно, где именно стоит добавлять `#define NOMINMAX`, например, если добавление, казалось бы, в правильном месте не решает проблему. Тогда можно попробовать определить `NOMINMAX` через дополнительный ключ компилятора:

   ```
   > cl.exe -DNOMINMAX ...
   ```

   В Visual Studio это делается через *Configuration Properties → C/C++ → Preprocessor → Preprocessor Definitions* в свойствах проекта.
3. При одновременном использовании библиотек, опирающихся на наличие функционала макросов `min`, `max`, предыдущее решение может вызывать проблемы типа:

   > error C3861: 'min': identifier not found

   В таком случае можно дополнить первое решение внесением стандартных функций `std::min`, `std::max` в проблемное пространство имён (откуда возникла ошибка "identifier not found"). [Например](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4914108/3240681):

   ```
   #define NOMINMAX
   #include <algorithm>
   namespace Gdiplus
   {
       using std::min;
       using std::max;
   }
   ```
4. Макросы `min`, `max` можно вовсе не отменять, а вызовы `std::min` и `std::max` [обернуть в скобки](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13420838/3240681):

   ```
   (std::min)(x, y);
   ```

   В таком виде макроподстановка не выполняется, т.к. для этого требуется иметь *открывающую* скобку (с возможными пробельными символами) сразу за потенциальным функциональным макросом, а мы это блокировали наличием *закрывающей* скобки.
5. Локально отменить макрос и после вызова функции вернуть с помощью [`push_macro/pop_macro`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/push-macro):

   ```
   max(x, y);                // Подстановка макроса
   #pragma push_macro("max")
   #undef max
   std::max(x, y);           // Вызов функции  
   #pragma pop_macro("max")
   max(x, y);                // Снова подстановка макроса
   ```

Answer (score 10):

Начните программу со строки

```
#define NOMINMAX
```

Она отменяет макросы `min` и `max` в стандартных заголовочных файлах Windows.